# Unable to update Mongoose Nested Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've spent a day going through Mongoose documentation and posts on here and while I'm almost certain I have the code as prescribed in all those solved posts I simply cannot get my code to work. :(

The schema is relatively complex but by no means as complex as I've seen:

```
const hrUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  displayName: String,
  school: String,
  leaveAuthoriser: String,
  holidayLeft: Number,
  holidayAllowed: Number,
  discretionaryDays: Number,
  emailAddress: String,
  termTimeOnly: Boolean,
  noOfAdditionalContractedDays: Number,
  noOfAdditionalContractedDaysLeft: Number,
  teachingStaff: Boolean,
  employStartDate: String,
  notes: String,
  loginAttempts: Number,
  lineManages: [{
    staffName: String
  }],
  bookedHoliday: [{
    dateEntered: String,
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String,
    daysTaken: Number,
    status: String,
    approvedBy: String,
    leaveType: String,
    declineReason: String
  }],
  additionalContractedDays: [{
    acdDateEntered: String,
    acdStartDate: String,
    acdEndDate: String,
    acdDaysTaken: Number,
    acdStatus: String,
    acdApprovedBy: String,
    acdDeclineReason: String
  }],
  perfMan: [{
    year: Number,
    selfReview: {
      sref1: String,
      sref2: String,
      sref3: String,
      sref4: String,
      sref5: String,
      status: String,
      dateStarted: String,
      dateCompleted: String,
      signedOff: Boolean
    },
    stage1: {
      objectives : [
        {
          objective: String,
          objectiveLinkToSchoolTeam: String,
          objectiveProgress: Boolean
        }
      ],
      personalDevelopment: String,
      resourcesTraining: String,
      appraiserSignOff: Boolean,
      appraiseeSignOff: Boolean
    },
    stage2: {
      feedback: String,
      appraiserSignOff: Boolean,
      appraiseeSignOff: Boolean
    },
    stage3: {
      feedback: String,
      appraiserSignOff: Boolean,
      appraiseeSignOff: Boolean
    }

  }]
});
```

Basically I want to update perfMan.stage1.objectives.objectiveProgress, example of what data in that might look like is:

```
"perfMan" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60cb502631dcea3eaaae6853"), 
            "selfReview" : {
                "sref1" : "I have no strength", 
                "sref2" : "No developments", 
                "sref3" : "None I'm brill", 
                "sref4" : "The department has no aims", 
                "signedOff" : true
            }, 
            "stage1" : {
                "objectives" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60cb502631dcea3eaaae6854"), 
                        "objective" : "Objective is pants", 
                        "objectiveLinkToSchoolTeam" : "I hate objectives!", 
                        "objectiveProgress" : false
                    }, 
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("60cb502631dcea3eaaae6855"), 
                        "objective" : "My second Objectoves", 
                        "objectiveLinkToSchoolTeam" : "My Second reasons", 
                        "objectiveProgress" : false
                    }
                ], 
                "personalDevelopment" : "My personal Development", 
                "resourcesTraining" : "My Resources"
            }, 
            "stage2" : {
                "feedback" : "Keep working HARD", 
                "appraiserSignOff" : true
            }, 
            "stage3" : {
                "feedback" : "Yoy've done really well", 
                "appraiserSignOff" : true
            }, 
            "year" : NumberInt(2021)
        }
    ]
```

I've read about and tried to implement this by using arrayFilters which to me seems to exactly what I want, I've checked my Mongoose version (hosted) and it's 4.4.6 so I'm easily running above 3.6 which I think is what's needed.

My current code looks like this, I've confirmed the find is getting the right data:

```
 HRUser.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"username": username},
    {"$set": {"perfMan.$[perfMan].stage1.objectives.$[objectives].objectiveProgress" : true}},
    {"arrayFilters" : [{ "perfMan._id": ObjectId("" + perfmanID + "") },{ "objectives._id": ObjectId("" + objectiveID + "") }]}
  ),
  function (err, response) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(response);
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Successfully updated staff member details.");
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  };
```

If somebody could spot my obviously glaring error I would be for ever grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not looking at a screen all weekend and reading through the documentation for the billionth time I decided to change tack! I can't see any limitations on the number of arrayFilters, or for that matter objectID use within them, and I'm 99% certain both object IDs are correct but, after changing the code to the below, basically using a mix of a positional operator $ based on the search of the same first objectID AND an arrayFilter element it's now working! Code below:

```
  HRUser.findOneAndUpdate({
    perfMan: {
      $elemMatch: {
        _id: ObjectId("" + perfManID + "")
      }
    }
  },
  {"$set": {"perfMan.$.stage1.objectives.$[objectives].objectiveProgress" : false}},
  {"arrayFilters" : [{ "objectives._id": ObjectId("" + objectiveID + "") }]},
  function (err, response) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(response);
  });
```